# RegEx to match characters of same type

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that cannot contain more than 3 consecutive characters of same type

```
ABC - valid
@@@ - valid
123 - valid
ABCD - not valid
ABC!@# - valid
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: How do you define **same type**?

Comment: Alphabets, Numbers and special characters - are individual types

Comment: Is `_` a  special char? Is `ą` a  special char?

Comment: Find string __not__ match this regex
`([a-zA-Z]{4,})|([0-9]{4,})|([^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{4,})` and custom it if you have other definition of `type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (!/[a-z]{4}|\d{4}|[^a-z\d]{4}/i.test(s)) { console.log("valid"); }
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLsHWR/2)

The `/[a-z]{4}|\d{4}|[^a-z\d]{4}/i` regex will match in case insensitive way (due to `/i`) 4 consecutive ASCII letters (`[a-z]{4}`) or 4 consecutive digits (`\d{4}`), or 4 chars other than ASCII letters and digits (`[^a-z\d]{4}`).

The `!/regex/.test()` check will return false whenever the match is found.

```js
var strs = ['ABC','@@@','123','ABC!@#','ABCD'];
var rx = /[a-z]{4}|\d{4}|[^a-z\d]{4}/i;
for (var s of strs) {
  if (!rx.test(s)) {
    console.log(s, ": valid"); 
  }  else  {
     console.log(s, ": invalid"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but the Link to the RegEx Demo show a different RegEx

Comment: Yes, I was writing a more complicated solution when I thought it should be simiplified.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string based on your types, then check the length is less than 3, I don't think this is possible with just RegExp.

```js
const tests = [
  'ABC',
  '@@@',
  '123',
  'ABCD',
  'ABC!@#'
]

function validate(string){
  return string.split(/([A-Z]+|[0-9]+|@+|\W+)/)
    .every(str => str.length <= 3)
}

console.log(
  tests.map(validate)
)
```